# How to run migrations on a different database server through Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, rails-migrations

We need to add the credentials of a database in `database.yml` file under a different environment like `remote_database`:

```
remote_database:
  adapter:
  encoding:
  username:
  ...
```

And after adding all this, running the following command from the local terminal does the job:

```
RAILS_ENV=remote_database rails db:migrate
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing on Heroku. I have pushed the changes in `config/database.yml`, and I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=remote_database heroku run rake db:migrate
# or
heroku run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=remote_database
```

Seems like Heroku is completely ignoring `RAILS_ENV` or the settings for `remote_database` env in `config/database.yml` file. Heroku always makes the changes in the regular database server connected with it that can be found at `DATABASE_URL`.

Is there a way to run the migrations on a different database server through Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku injects `database.yml` and overrides it completely with Rails under 4.1 version or overrides partially and allows a way for us to prevent overriding from Rails 4.1. Check the complete explanation about Rails database connection behaviour on [Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior)

So, in your case

- **If you are using Rails 4.1+**: you may try to add `url` key to your `database.yml` as described in `Active Record 4.1+ Escape Valve` section of above link.
- **If you are using Rails under 4.1 version**: override database connection by an initializer. See [Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections) ("Otherwise if you are using an older version of Rails you will need to use an initializer" section)